# Execution time of multithreaded python program

Tags: python, multithreading

Considering GIL, I expected this program to finish in 9 seconds, but to my surprise, it ends in 4 seconds. Looking for probable reasons or am I missing something?

```
import time
import threading

def get_data(start, end):
    res = []
    for i in range(start, end):
        time.sleep(1)
        res.append(i)
    print res


range_list = [(1,4), (4,7), (6,10)]
for r in range_list:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_data, args = (r[0], r[1]))
    t.start()
```

Time of execution:-

Without threading - 9sec

With threading - 4 sec

Comment: Since you are spawning 3 threads, and none of them uses a shared resource, they will all sleep and finish *at the same time*, so 4 seconds is correct.

Comment: `sleep` releases the GIL.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205328/scheduling-issues-in-python

Comment: ok, thanks @cdarke. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you don't use multithreading this program finish in 9 seconds because python runs lines one by one so when you put time.sleep(1), python just wait one second and on the other hand do not anything. But when you use multithreading the program runs thread functions separately. So for example if you call thread function 2 times, the thread function runs line by line seperately in the same time.

In this program, you call thread function for 3 times. First call, python wait 3 seconds for i =1,i=2,i=3 and second call, python wait 3 seconds for i =4,i=5,i=6 and final call  python wait 4 seconds for i =6,i=7,i=8,i=9. This codes runs separately each other so this program finish in 4 second because the biggest time is 4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the response but you are wrong here. Python threading does not work the same way as in other languages. GIL will not let the threads execute this way. It is time.sleep method that skipped it. If at all time.sleep was replaced by a heavy computation(CPU intensive) that takes 1 sec to execute, the time of execution would not decrease even if you use multithreading.